# Enable network for guest session in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, lubuntu, guest-session

When using the guest session it indicates that network is disabled and i can't enable it (it is grey)

How can i activate the network (eth0) for the guest session?

Comment: Are you using a regular session on the same computer too?

Answer (score 0):

In your regular user-account (one with sudo privileges) check if the connection you want to use is aviable for all users in the networkmanager

(click on Network symbol, edit connections, connection you want to use, edit, on the bottom of the window: check: aviable for all users(or likewise).

You may have to enter (sudo enabled) password.